# Does laptop HP dv7-4045 support i5-520M?

Tags: laptop, cpu, compatibility

When bought, HP dv7-4045 is equipped with quad core i7-720QM CPU. But, unfortunately, the laptop's cooling system is badly designed and CPU somewhat aged over time. The temperature now reaches 90 degrees Centigrade and fan is very noisy.

I bought less power hungry CPU dual core i5-520M as a replace. But it didn't work. The screen never turned on and fan was spinning. Firstly I thought that the problem is somehow connected with built-in GPU sending video signal to nowhere. But pressing power on/off button it took ~5 sec to shut is off, which indicated that it froze.

From [service manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02666747) (p.98):
[image]

Does the laptop hp dv7 4045 support i5-520M or I have got faulty CPU?

Comment: Possibly installed incorrectly, double check your work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have found a list of compatible CPUs. It is in said above service manual in chapter 1:
[image]

> Update:
> After further research, I have found that i7-720qm is from completely different processor family Clarksfield, while i5-560m is from Arrandale.
>
> And indeed, I borrowed a laptop with i5-560m. So it is confirmed now. My CPU didn't work on that laptop, i5-560m didn't work on my laptop. The screen was just black, while fan was spinning.

Comment: I don''t see it in your list?

Comment: @Moab, thank you for noticing that, that row is on the next page. I have included it into the screenshot